# The difference between libwinpthread.a and libpthread.a?

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm using Mingw64 for Windows(of course), and I usually statically link against libwinpthread.a. But I have noticed that there is also a library called libpthread.a (without the win). I can see that they have different sizes, so something must be different. If I create a very simple program with thread library included, I can see that the compiled code also is in different sizes, when I use the tag -libpthread instead of -libwinpthread.

I know that winpthread is using a BSD-license. And in Linux pthread is using the LGPL-license. So can it be something about the license? Maybe libpthread is using LGPL and libwinpthread is using BSD? I don't know.

I hope someone here can help me. Something must be different, because I get different result.

Comment: I'm guessing - guessing - that libwinpthread.a links libpthread.a and is intended to allow you to seamlessly compile using pthreads on both Windows and Linux.  If you're just compiling for Linux only I don't think you need to link libwinpthread at all.

Comment: Maybe so :). Could be. But I after I send this question, I used a hex editor to compare those files. And in libthread I can see the text "nanosleep.c" but in libwinpthread it doesn't exist. I don't know why :(. I guess there is more differences, but I'm too lazy to compare every byte :).

Comment: nanosleep isn't available on Windows because Windows has no OS support for its contract.  This basically proves my theory.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. You learn something new everyday :). Thanks for a great answer :). I'm new here, I don't know how to mark your answer as the right one :(.
But thanks anyway :).

Comment: I do it to help, not for the votes.  Thank you though, and enjoy SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is embarrassing, but I finally find the difference between libpthread.a and libwinpthread.a.
They are 99.9%(you could say 100%) identically.

The only difference is that libwinpthread.a is more compressed.
I tried to compile the winpthread-code with make-command.
And then I install it with "make install" command.
But if I instead install it with "make install-strip" it will install an a-file without symbols table.
With the exact same result as the already installed a-files.

So use the tag -lwinpthread if you want to use winpthread(static linking) with no symbols table.
If you do want to have the symbols table for winpthread, use the tag -lpthread.

A static library(a-file) is just an archive format(like tar) with o-files inside.
To view an a-file you will need for Windows either mingw-w64, cygwin or msys2 or similar.
So view an a-file by writing in a terminal: ar -t -file.a

If you want to extract the a-file you can write: ar -x file.a

Now you will have several o-files.
You can view the content inside an o-file by writing: nm -C file.o

If you want to diassembler an o-file you can just write: objdump -D file.o

Or write the data to a file: objdump -D file.o > obj_arm.txt

Do that with one o-file from libpthread and one o-file from libwinpthread.
And then compare the txt-files with your favorite software.
They will be 100% identically.

Comment: A static library *is* an [`ar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) archive of object files,
but `ar` archives are not compressed. More like `tar` than `zip`.

Comment: Thank you :). Edit my answer.